# Cannot use custom library in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_download.htm library in my project for resizing images. However, when I submit form it gives this error

[image]

I have loaded the library in the autoloader and I renamed library to "my_upload" and gave the same class name.

[image]

However, I do not know why this error occurs.

And here is my controller:

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller{

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }


        public function add() {

            if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('not_loggedin','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Please Login</div>');
                redirect('login');
             }
            $data['title'] = 'Ədd nyus';


            $data['author'] = $this->Blog_model->get_author();
            $data['category'] = $this->Blog_model->get_category();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('blog/add', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function create() {

            if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('not_loggedin','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Please Login</div>');
                redirect('login');
             }

            //insert image    

             $now = date("YmdHis");
             $this->my_upload->upload($_FILES["userfile"]);
             if ( $this->my_upload->uploaded == true  ) {
              $this->my_upload->allowed               = array('jpg|png');
              $this->my_upload->file_new_name_body    = 'image_resized' . $now;
              $this->my_upload->image_resize          = true;
              $this->my_upload->image_ratio_fill      = true;
              $this->my_upload->image_x               = 360;
              $this->my_upload->image_y               = 236;
              // $this->my_upload->image_ratio_y         = true;
              $this->my_upload->process('C:\xampp\htdocs\edu-center\assets\img\blog');
              if ( $this->my_upload->processed == true ) {
                $this->my_upload->clean();
                $post_image = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];  
              }
            } else {
                $post_image = '';
            }

            //insert the user registration details into database
            $randnum = mt_rand(100000,999999);
            $slugtitle = mb_strtolower($this->input->post('title_az'), 'UTF-8') . '-' .$randnum;
            $slug = url_title($slugtitle);

            $post_image = str_replace(' ', '_', $post_image);   
            $post_image = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $post_image);

            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Baku');
            $data = array(
                'title_az' => strip_tags($this->input->post('title_az')),
                'title_rus' => strip_tags($this->input->post('title_rus')),
                'author_id' => $this->input->post('author_id'),
                'category_id' => strip_tags($this->input->post('category')),
                'body_az' => $this->input->post('body_az'),
                'body_rus' => $this->input->post('body_rus'),
                'date' => date("d-m-Y"),
                'news_slug' => $slug,
                'img' => $post_image
            );

        $this->Blog_model->add_news($data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('changed_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Ваши изменения были сохранены!</div>');
        redirect('blog');
    }
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: You might be missing `()`  `$this->my_upload->uploaded()` and `$this->my_upload->processed()`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 the same error :(

Comment: Just to point out You have doubled up on `$this->my_upload->uploaded` this

Answer (score 1):

imho the best way is to create a third party library for that
copy your class into your folder `application/third_party/upload/`

and in your controller you simply inlcude this file like:

```
require_once(APPPATH."third_party/upload/my_upload.php");
$objUpload = new my_upload($_FILES);
```

If you really want a library for that try the following:

The problem is your library gets instantiated by CI - you don't really have control over the constructor

the only way you could do is to include a "wrapper" library
e.g.

```
<?php

require_once(APPPATH."libraries/my_upload.php");

class Uploadwrapper_library
{
    public function get($files)
    {
        return new my_upload($files);
    }
}
```

in your controller you could do

```
$this->load->library("uploadwrapper_library");
$objMyUpload = $this->uploadwrapper_library->get($_FILES);
```

Comment: It means if I use the first method you wrote, I should use `$objUpload->`  instead of `$this->my_upload->` ?

Comment: It inserts the data to the DB however except img name. And it throws these errors.  https://imgur.com/a/x7G6I

Comment: no offense men but this is an entire different error in your library which i don't know anything about...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look at the file - **system/libraries/Upload.php** it's constructor requires a parameter...

```
public function __construct($config = array())
```

So with your MY_Upload class which is CI's way to allow you to override core classes, you need to follow suit with the class you are extending.

You've not shown your constructor so I don't know what you have attempted with your constructor...

Comment: I do not have a constructor in my_upload.php

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070590/codeigniter-file-upload-with-verot-upload-class-and-dropzone-js